# Getting Error :malloc: *** error for object 0x1107e790: pointer being freed was not allocated *** set a breakpoint in malloc_error_break to debug

Tags: memory-management, ios6, malloc, breakpoints, nszombie

I am getting the following Output in NSZombie,

[image]

I don't know How to solve it:

I am using the Following Code :

```
        AsyncronousUIImage *image=[[AsyncronousUIImage alloc] init];
        [image loadImageFromURL:imageURL inImageView:templateView];
        image.delegate=self;
```

Comment: How about setting a breakpoint in `malloc_error_break` and examining the stack?

Comment: i already set ,and getting above output. i am using xcode 4.6 with ARC enable mode.